# SqlAlchemy - Classic Mapping Inheritance - Instance has Null Identity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm seeing a NULL Identity key error when trying to write out an object mapped to a table that inherits another one. I've found this example works fine when using the [Declarative approach](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping), but not when using the [Classical one](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings).

The tables are set up as follows:

```py
objecttypes = Table('objecttypes', metadata,
                    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('name', String)
                    )
things = Table('things', metadata,
               Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
               Column('name', String),
               Column('object_type_id', Integer, ForeignKey('objecttypes.id')),
               Column('version', Integer),
               Column('timeCreated', DateTime)
               )
locations = Table('locations', metadata,
                  Column('id', Integer, ForeignKey('things.id'), primary_key=True))

objecttypes = Table('objecttypes', metadata,
                    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('name', String)
                    )
mapper(Thing, things, version_id_col=things.c.version,
       polymorphic_on="object_type_id",
       with_polymorphic='*',
       polymorphic_load='inline',
       properties={
           'objectType': relationship(ObjectType, cascade_backrefs=False)
       })
mapper(Location, locations, polymorphic_identity=typeDict['location'].id)
```

The classes are set up as:

```py
class ObjectType(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "ObjectType({}, id={})".format(self.name, self.id)

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwds):
        for key in kwds:
            setattr(self, key, kwds[key])
        return

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, id={}, type={}, version={}".format(self.name, self.id, self.objectType, self.version)

class Location(Thing):
    pass
```

I get the error when  I try creating and merging a new Location:

```py
def write(obj):
    session = scopedSessionFactory()
    obj = session.merge(obj)
    session.commit()
    return obj

# typeDict is a predefined list ObjectType records
tokyo = Location(name="tokyo", objectType=typeDict['location'])
tokyo = write(tokyo)
```

The error shows up as:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <Location at 0x10473a950> has a NULL identity key.
```

Full example available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/funseiki/48a40573475a9be5caa2990acf523848).

Comment: it looks like some value is not getting set in Location instance.

Comment: please, change the line to:```mapper(Location, locations, inherits=Thing, polymorphic_identity=typeDict['location'].id)```. I think you are missing this ```inherits=Thing```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem to be the following and might be found in this subtle lines in the SQLA docs:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.params.inherits

I report it here and bold the key pieces that might point to at least a partial solution to your problem:

> A mapped class or the corresponding Mapper of one indicating a superclass to which this Mapper should inherit from. The mapped class here must be a subclass of the other mapper’s class. **When using Declarative, this argument is passed automatically as a result of the natural class hierarchy of the declared classes**.

So, when using declarative, you do not bump into this problem as this is passed automatically but it does not for classical approach so it needs to be specified.

As a result of this, your mapper line for Location I believe should be the following:

```
mapper(Location, locations, inherits=Thing, polymorphic_identity=typeDict['location'].id)
```

where you notice the addition of `inherits=Thing`.

Indeed, with your code I reproduce your same error but doing this modification I do not get that error anymore.
I haven't checked to all the rest of the code if ok the way it is.

---

**UPDATE**:
The following SO posts show similar examples of inheritance without any explicit reference to the SQLA doc.

[SQLAlchemy, polymorphic inheritance with classical mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745792/sqlalchemy-polymorphic-inheritance-with-classical-mapping)

[Need classic mapper example for SqlAlchemy single table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665708/need-classic-mapper-example-for-sqlalchemy-single-table-inheritance)

Comment: Yep, this was it. I actually found it a few minutes after I posted the bounty, but figured it was more fun to see if anyone could figure it out before the bounty was up. Nice catch.